# cloud firestore problem in flutter while installation

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

when i tried toinstall cloud firestore sdk :
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

## The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1
firebase_core: ^0.7.0

keep showing this error :
Running "flutter pub get" in mysecondapp...
Got socket error trying to find package cloud_firestore at https://pub.dartlang.org.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

Comment: The case may be that your internet connection may not be proper. Please try again.

Comment: no sir , it was not a connection problem , i resolve this problem like so : i executed cmd Prompt ,  executed :ipconfig /flushdns ,finally executed :netsh winsock reset , rerun pc then problem resolved , thank you

Comment: @SarahBensalem, great job. Can you share this solution as the answer in the form below, so people can find this solution?

Answer (score 1):

@SarahBensalem shared that she solved the socket issue by running the cmd command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh winsock reset
```

and afterwards restarted the pc.